# Google Sheets border/gridline variable thickness when colour filled

Tags: google-sheets

When I fill cells with colour some cells appear to fill just the cell and some fill the cell and the border/gridline.
I have tried adding and deleting borders and altering the colour fill via conditional formatting.
However I can see no difference between affected cells' settings.

[image: Example of cells filled red, but with different outcomes]

Please could someone advise how to prevent this happening?
Thank you!

Comment: it looks like the answers below are both correct and helped you fix your formatting issue. Therefore you should mark one of the answers as accepted, so others can know these helped and can learn from the thread.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that Gib, will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When [referring to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64295879/1527780) *"select **Borders -> Clear Borders**"*, in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64295646/google-sheets-border-gridline-variable-thickness-when-colour-filled#comment113696068_64295879) you mentioned:

> Sadly, it does not work for me.

To fix the issue you should **clear the fill of the cell bellow and next to the cell in reference**.

Why?
Because in **either** a cell is filled with white **or** is reset, the `Fill colour` shows `White`.
This can be confusing, but...

[image]

Comment: Done.  Apologies for getting it wrong.  Just to be clear, both answers got the right answer, once I had offered the information required which was an upload of an example of the problem.  It was nothing to do with borders and everything to do with the cells below being filled with white, which resetting fixed.  Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

Difficult to tell exactly what is causing it from just a screen shot, but my guess is that it is the border setting from the cells below the red cell that is actually the issue.

Here I recreate the problem with cell F12 having a custom border while cell G12 does not have any:

[image]

So try highlighting both of your "Y" cells at the bottom of the red "N" cells, then select **Borders** -> **Clear Borders**

[image]

If above works, then my recommendation will be to Clear Borders for all cells (if your sheet is not too complex already) and then start your formatting again.

**After OP provided a link to the sample Google Sheet, it is clear that the issue is that the cell below (i.e. cell A4 in the sample) had a White fill colour, while cell B4 did not.**

If the fill in A4 is Reset (cleared) then the red fill in A3:B3 will match. To illustrate this point, I duplicated the OP's A1:B5 range to A8:B12, then Reset (cleared) the fill colour in A11:B12. As screen shot shows, the red fill in A10:B10 then appears as identical.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your in-depth response.  Sadly, it does not work for me.  Apologies for only putting on a screenshot; here's a mini version of the spreadsheet with the problem:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hv__skGnNpfR1-fpEb3u726WGiQtQENFpLKRZG1CItY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: As @marikamitsos also mentioned below, your issue is the fill colour of the cell below. Specifically, if you **clear (reset) the fill of your cell A4** then the red fill in A3:B3 will match. To illustrate this point, I have duplicated your A1:B5 range to A8:B12 and Reset the fill colour. As you can see, the red fill in A10:B10 then matches.

Comment: Thank you for everyone's very helpful and quick replies.  It is so obvious...when you know what to look for!  To see the difference between white fill and no fill is not at all clear, with even the white box being ticked in the fill colour selection after completing a reset.  
Incidentally, I do not recall ever filling a cell with white; why would I when they appear to be white already?  I wonder how the issue came about in the first place therefore.